# Shopify cart, how to know if max quantity of product is reached with req to change.js or update.js?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am working on a cart and I am trying to determine if a max quantity is reached.

For example, when a customer clicks on the "Add to Cart" button, that one uses the add.js call, and if the user already has the max quantity in his cart, it returns a 422 status code, saying that max quantity is reached.

However, if the customer clicks on the + button in the cart to increase quantity (which normally works just fine the way I have it!), I am using the `change.js` call to increase (or decrease) the quantity, but once I reach the max quantity, it no longer increases, but it still returns status 200 as if everything is fine, and I have no way of detecting wether max quantity is reached with `change.js`. Data object that I am sending is:

```
{
  id: itemID,
  quantity: newQuantity,
}
```

I have also tried to do it with the `update.js`, and that is even allowing me to update the cart to quantities that are not available (for example, available quantity is 4, I got it up to 12!)! Still no errors.

```
{
  updates: {
    [`${itemID}`]: newQuantity
}
```

No way that I can find in the cart API documentation https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart

So how do I determine wether a max quantity is reached with change.js?